# Why is Tensorflow "save_model" failing?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working in Tensorflow 2.0.0, and trying to save a  model.  Here's the code I'm using (thanks to @m-innat for suggesting to simplify the
example model)

```
class SimpleModel( tf.keras.Model ):
    def __init__( self, **kwargs ):
        super( SimpleModel, self ).__init__( **kwargs )
        self.conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D( filters = 5, kernel_size = 3, padding = "SAME" )
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense( 1 )
    def call( self, x ):
        x = self.conv( x )
        x = self.dense( x )
        return x

simple_model = SimpleModel()

input_shape = ( 3, 4, 5 )
x = tf.random.normal( shape = input_shape )
y = tf.random.normal( shape = ( 3, 4, 1 ) )
y_pred = simple_model( x )
print( "y_pred", y_pred )

tf.keras.models.save_model( translation_model, 
    "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SimpleModel.tf", save_format = "tf" )
```

However, the `save_model` call gives an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Nothing in the call stack suggests what the underlying problem is.  Can you please help?

Comment: Try to reproduce your error with simple mode and provide full reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the fact that the input shapes of the layers are not set. This can be done by calling one time the methods `simple_model.fit` or `simple_model.predict`.

For example, in your code, you can call `y_pred = simple_model.predict( x )`.

In this way, the model is correctly saved as I checked in the code below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class SimpleModel( tf.keras.Model ):
    def __init__( self, **kwargs ):
        super( SimpleModel, self ).__init__( **kwargs )
        self.conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D( filters = 5, kernel_size = 3, padding = "SAME" )
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense( 1 )
    def call( self, x ):
        x = self.conv( x )
        x = self.dense( x )
        return x

simple_model = SimpleModel()

input_shape = ( 3, 4, 5 )
x = tf.random.normal( shape = input_shape )
y = tf.random.normal( shape = ( 3, 4, 1 ) )
y_pred = simple_model.predict( x )
print( "y_pred", y_pred )

tf.keras.models.save_model( simple_model, 
    "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SimpleModel.tf", save_format = "tf" )

# Output:
# y_pred [[[-0.4533468 ]
#  [ 1.3261242 ]
#  [-1.0296338 ]
#  [-1.1136482 ]] ...

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SimpleModel.tf')
model.predict(x)

# Output:
#array([[[-0.4533468 ],
#        [ 1.3261242 ],
#        [-1.0296338 ],
#        [-1.1136482 ]], ...
```

Comment: welcome and thanks! for your help.   However, looking at the original posting, I realize there was a mistake that explains the problem:   The call to ```save_model``` refers to the wrong model ```translation_model```.   Changing the argument to ```simple_model``` as Luigi did fixes the problem.

Comment: Well, if you call directly the ```simple_model``` without ```predict``` there is still an error about the undefined shapes while saving the model. At least in TF 2.0.0 where I tried your code.